# How to change/input different attributes for Passport.js other then 'username' and 'password'

Tags: node.js, html, passport.js

I am setting up a authentication for my website but unable to do so.
For my input i only have Password and the **Username is not required**.
Passport.js expects two values in the .Serialize Function though i want to change it to one input.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id); //only works when username:password are being sent & ignores rest 

});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  User.findByName(id, function(err, user) {
    cb(err, user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here username is used to find/save the user in the database,and then passport,js verifies the password for login or encodes for registration

Comment: but i only want to use one. like password only

Comment: You can use [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) it takes in password and returns you encoded password which you can save in database